# python リストの取り扱いと、CSV出力について

Tags: python, python3, csv

リストの取り扱いと、CSV出力について、どうも理解が出来ず困っております。

スクレイピング結果をCSVに書き出す学習をしておりますが、sample_02.pyのコードで、リストをCSVに書き出すことができません。

どの様にすれば、CSVに書き出すことができるかお教えください。

`writer.writerow([elem.text, elem.get("href")])`の部分で、取得したテキストとリンクが格納されていると思いますが、`[elem.text, elem.get("href")`は、カンマで結合？区切られているということになるのでしょうか？

```py
# sample_01.py

import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.yahoo.co.jp/"
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

topics = soup.find(id = "Topics")

# aタグのテキスト部分とhrefで取得したURLをCSV形式で書き出す
with open("info_01.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf_8") as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for elem in topics.find_all("a"):
        writer.writerow([elem.text, elem.get("href")])
```

実行結果（成功）

```
臨時国会 法案成立率は95.5%NEW,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447265
被害者救済法が成立,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447261
来週は寒さ厳しく 西日本で雪恐れ,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447258
```

次に、配列の取り扱いの学習のため、`elem.text`と`elem.get("href")`以下の様に、一旦、配列に格納し、`writerows`で一気に書き出す処理を行ってみましたが、うまくできません。

```py
# sample_02.py

tag_li = []
link_li = []
with open("info-2.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf_8") as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for elem in topics.find_all("a"):
        tag_li.append(elem.text)
        link_li.append(elem.get("href"))
    
    writer.writerows([tag_li, link_li])
```

実行結果（失敗　なぜ？？）

```
臨時国会 法案成立率は95.5%NEW,被害者救済法が成立,来週は寒さ厳しく 西日本で雪恐れ,露、イランとドローン生産検討かNEW,工場で黄色いガス漏れ 付近に規制,奨学金650万円 返済終わりは50代,うるさい? 子連れ批判に医師訴えNEW,しらふのW杯 現地「意外に」好評NEW,かまくら出現12/10(土) 16:02共同通信,もっと見る,トピックス一覧
https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447265,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447261,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447258,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447256,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447263,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447249,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447264,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6447259,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/b58cff17ed19d2c0d5e64db996d0ebddc5f2d07a/images/000,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks,https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単なプログラムを例に取ると

```py
import csv
import io

with io.StringIO() as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)

    # writerow は１行分を書き込む
    writer.writerow(['1行目',110,120])

    # writerows は複数行を書き込む
    data = [['2行目',210,220],['3行目',310,320]]
    writer.writerows(data)
    res = fp.getvalue()

print(res)
# 1行目,110,120
# 2行目,210,220
# 3行目,310,320
```

上記のような構造を持てばいいので

`writer.writerow([elem.text, elem.get("href")])`
で１行分を書き込めているなら以下のように蓄えるだけです

```py
lines = []
for elem in topics.find_all("a"):
    line = [elem.text, elem.get("href")]
    lines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `writer.writerow([elem.text, elem.get("href")])` の部分で、取得したテキストとリンクが格納されていると思いますが、`[elem.text, elem.get("href")]` は、カンマで結合？区切られているということになるのでしょうか？

リストは要素を順番に保持しているだけで，要素をカンマで結合しているのは `csv.writer(w).writerow()` です。この部分を敢えて `w.write()` で記述すると下記になります。

```
w.write(','.join([elem.text, elem.get("href")]) + '\r\n')
```

なお，RFC4180（CSVファイルの一般的書式）に従いデフォルトで付加される改行コードが `'\r\n'`（CRLF(0x0d, 0x0a)）のため，Windows の場合は（既に対応されていますが）`open()` の改行コードの自動変換（`'\n'` -> `'\r\n'`）設定を無効（`newline=''` 有り）にする必要があります。
または `csv.writer(w, lineterminator='\n').writerow()` で改行コードを `'\n'`（LF）に指定して `open()` の改行コードの自動変換設定を有効（`newline=''` 無し）にする方法もあります。

一方，`writerows()` の一括書き込み方法は既に解決済みですが，念のため記述例を下記に示します。

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.yahoo.co.jp/', timeout=5)
topics = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser').find(id='Topics')

lines = [[e.text, e.get('href')] for e in topics.find_all('a')]

with open('info_02.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n').writerows(lines)
```